# Can I store my pixels somewhere so I don't lose them when I die?

Tags: starbound

I die all the time. My pixel balance hovers around zero as a result. I'm trying to save up for armor but my nonstop deaths are making that difficult.

Is there anywhere I can store my pixels so that when I die, I won't lose a bunch of them?

Comment: Get better. Problem solved. And no, you cannot save them.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only person dying constantly

Comment: @shanodin ^^ I mean seriously this game is hard.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only way to store pixels (as of yet) is via the [Pixel Compressor](http://starbounder.org/Pixel_Compressor).

[image]

> Pixel Compressor is a crafting station used to turn pixels into tradeable/storable items called voxels. Decompressing these voxels will yield the equivalent amount of pixels back, it provides a way to trade pixels to others as well as protect pixel loss from death.

This crafting station is crafted at the Architect's Table (third tier Inventor's Table), and requires

- 15 x Gold Bars
- 15 x Durasteel Bars

You can only compress 1000, 2000, 5000 and 10000 pixels. To decompress them, simple use the decompress table (which acts much like the sell window on a merchant).

Comment: Thank you for posting a superb answer.  You definitely deserve the bounty reward for this.

Answer (score 12):

Pixels are the main currency in Starbound. They can't be stored in regular containers like other items. The later in the game you get, the more important they become for crafting everything as part of the base crafting cost.  You also lose 30% of pixels upon death.

3D printing has advanced so far in the game universe that the universal currency form has become 3D Printer fuel, called Pixels.[1](http://starbounder.org/Pixel)  Pixels can be used to buy and trade items in game, as well as operate the player's 3D Printer to manufacture printed items.

In order to store pixels, you need a pixel converter.  Pixel converters turn pixels into voxels, which lose 40% of the pixel value when converted, and can be turned into pixels again by using the Refinery. Dying twice will result in you losing 51% of your pixels, so storing them as voxels instead can save a significant amount of saved pixels.

[Supporting Article](http://starbounder.org/Pixel)

Comment: As of the patch going live in under 30 minutes there will be a way to store pixels.

Comment: "How to store in crafting" doesn't really answer anything.

Comment: Thus it's an edit. At the time of my answer, there was no method to store pixels. I shall update this information appropriately and keep my answer up to date

Comment: It's better to update the entire answer with new information rather than appending new information at the bottom, it's confusing to read otherwise.

Comment: Please format your answer as *one conclusive answer*, not a string of edits.

Comment: I'm almost constantly looking for answers to answer your question. RSS Feed set up and everything, I know when a new comment appears, even when I'm not on arqade.

I am taking some precious time to find your answer (which must be an apparent yes before something spontanious happens), but I only update with the latest things popping up. please be patient, I will keep searching

Comment: @EonRustedduPlessis I appreciate the time you're taking looking for this, and trying to keep your answer updated as the game changes. I  think it would be beneficial to get rid of some of that extra info... we don't really need a copy of the full wiki entry on pixels (particularly since that, too, will likely change over time and need updated). That 51% number is actually kind of misleading. The main points we care about for this question is "Can you save them somewhere?" (the answer appears to be "Yes") and "How do you save them somewhere?" (which I'm not sure we know the answer to)

Answer (score 2):

The current best way to store pixels is by using a [Pixel Compressor](http://starbounder.org/Pixel_Compressor) to craft Voxels. Voxels can be crafted in units of [1K](http://starbounder.org/1k_Voxel), [2K](http://starbounder.org/2k_Voxel), [5K](http://starbounder.org/5k_Voxel), or [10K](http://starbounder.org/10k_Voxel), and can then be stored like any item. The only costs for making the Voxels themselves is the pixels, but the refinery will initially cost 20 [Titanium Panel](http://starbounder.org/Titanium_Panel)s, and 20 [Steel Bar](http://starbounder.org/Steel_Bar)s, and requires the [Robotic Crafting Table](http://starbounder.org/Robotic_Crafting_Table), which is only available after beating the Tier 2 Boss.

When you want to get your pixels back out, just throw your Voxels into a [Refinery](http://starbounder.org/Refinery). They'll give back 60% of the pixels initially used. This makes Voxels more expensive than holding onto your pixels for a single death (30% cost), but cheaper than multiple deaths, and thus often useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a storage method but you can refine ore in the refinery for pixels (which is my main income), but you don't have to take the pixels out. What I usually do is refine some ore and only retrieve the pixels in the refinery when I need them to craft something. You can refine different types of ore and they will get added to the same pile. As far as I know there is no limit to the amount of pixels stored in the refinery this way.